# What is the list of numbers after a printed image in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, uiimage, firebase-storage

I am working on downloading images from firebase and saving those images in a list of dictionaries in Swift. As I started debugging I printed out the image and noticed there is a list of numbers after the image such as {0,0} I am wondering what this list is and why mine is printing {0,0} where other images I print have a higher set of numbers. I'm hoping this will lead me to the reason my image is not showing up.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers are the size of the `UIImage`. `{0, 0}` means your image has no size.

If I create an image of size 100x200, it will be shown in the printed message:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 100, height: 200))
print(UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!)
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

That prints:

```
<UIImage: 0x6040000a9120>, {100, 200}
```

> I'm hoping this will lead me to the reason my image is not showing up.

That's right, your images are not showing up because they have a size of 0x0!

Comment: `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize(width: 100, height: 105))` would be *slightly* more informative by showing which is `width` and which is `height`.

Comment: @vacawama Edited. I thought there's a convention that width is always first :)

Comment: Whenever there are 2 ways of doing things, they will be done 2 ways (driving on the left or right, big vs. little endian).  It's always good not to assume.  I up voted.